# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url

Tags: anaconda

I'm using conda to download a pkg, but failed with "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/bioconda/noarch/repodata.json". Hope the public mirrors in china could be supported soon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to Delete a file names ".condarc", which is in "C:/Users", you can search for it directly from the search bar.
Hope to help you :-)